# Diff between two textual html files

Tags: git, diff

I have a current version of a specification in HTML, and an older one. I want to be able to get a HTML file showing the differences between the older and the newer spec.

My strategy at the moment:

- find out how to get a diff between words, and not lines
- find out how to replace a diff output with maybe `<span class="addition">` and `<span class="removal">` to color the different additions and removals.

Any idea on how to do it fast?

Answer (score 3):

`git diff` has a `--word-diff` option :

> --word-diff[=<mode>]
>    Show a word diff, using the  to delimit changed words. By default, words are delimited by whitespace; see --word-diff-regex below. The  defaults to plain, and must be one of:
>
> color
>     Highlight changed words using only colors. Implies --color.
>
> plain
>     Show words as [-removed-] and {+added+}. Makes no attempts to escape the delimiters if they appear in the input, so the output may be ambiguous.
>
> porcelain
>     Use a special line-based format intended for script consumption. Added/removed/unchanged runs are printed in the usual unified diff format, starting with a +/-/ character at the beginning of the line and extending to the end of the
>     line. Newlines in the input are represented by a tilde ~ on a line of its own.
>
> none
>     Disable word diff again.
>
> Note that despite the name of the first mode, color is used to highlight the changed parts in all modes if enabled.

You can probably use `word-diff=plain` and bluntly replace `[-`, `-]`, `{+` and `+}` with your span tags,
or use the `porcelain` mode, which outputs a non ambiguous output format :
for each output line, the first character tells you what kind of data is represented on the remainder of the line :

- `~` : this is the end of a line (there should be no text nor spaces following a leading `~`)
- (space) : an unchanged chunk of text
- `+` : a block of text which was added
- `-` : a block of text which was deleted

Comment: great idea! Do you know how to get rid of `@@ -457,8 +468,9 @@` and have the entire text instead of jumps in the code?

Comment: `grep` out the lines you don't want

Comment: for your second question : do you mean from the `plain` output, or the `porcelain` output ?

Comment: No I meant, I want the entire file in the output. I don't want the diff to skip parts of the files. I think `-U1000000` (with a big value) works. I'm using the porcelain output.

Comment: I piped this porcelain output to disk with `>` and now I have weird glitches everywhere `^[[m` in the file. Do you know why?

Comment: edit: of course it was because I had `word-color` enabled :) fixed, thanks!

Comment: @David天宇Wong `^[[m` issue reminds me this https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423424/168003 related to colored mode effectively